# Граф точно не может быть связным, если

Tags: графы

Правильно ли я понимаю?

**Вопрос: Граф точно не будет связным, если**

1. В нём нет рёбер
   Да, если нет рёбер он точно не связный
2. В графе 4 вершины и 2 ребра
   Нет, вот визуализация
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. У какой-нибудь вершины рёбер меньше чем количество вершин -1
   Вообще не понимаю этот вопрос((((

Comment: 1) Да, 2) Да, 3) Нет. (это ответы на вопрос).

Comment: *если нет рёбер он точно не связный* Граф из одной вершины?

Comment: Третий вопрос точно так сформулирован?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одно из условий связности графа: "Существует путь из любой вершины в любую другую вершину".
Другое: "Существует путь из заданной вершины в любую другую вершину"

Тут в вопросе:

"количество вершин -1" = количество остальных вершин, кроме этой "какой-нибудь " вершины с малым числом рёбер.

Т.е.здесь фактически спрашивают: "если ребёр от вершины не хватает, чтобы к каждой вершине был от неё прямой путь (=прямое соединение ребром) - будет ли граф связным?"

Так как "Путь в графе — последовательность вершин, в которой каждая вершина соединена со следующей ребром" - то можем заключить, что прямое соединение ребром для связности не обязательно.

И да, вопросы 1 и 2 отвечены верно, на мой взгляд.